# ffmpeg with Popen (python) on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg with Popen. The ffmpeg command I am trying works on cmd but gives me error with Popen.

I am using the standalone ffmpeg .exe:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -offset_x 10 -offset_y 20 -show_region 1 -i desktop -video_size 1536x864 -b:v 2M -maxrate 1M -bufsize 1M -tune fastdecode -crf 15 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 <path>/video.mov -qp 1 -y -an
```

This gives me `Invalid argument`, but if I remove the last parameters in order to make the output the last thing on the string, I get a different error:

`Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

I tried to use `-f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture"` instead of the gdigrab, but both give me the same error with and without the parameters in the end.

Both commands work on command line.

On command line this `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` returns this:

```
[dshow @ 000001b24fa6a300] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 000001b24fa6a300]  "Integrated Webcam"
[dshow @ 000001b24fa6a300]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_1bcf&pid_2b8a&mi_00#6&2c03619a&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 000001b24fa6a300]  "UScreenCapture"
[dshow @ 000001b24fa6a300]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}\UScreenCapture"
[dshow @ 000001b24fa6a300] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 000001b24fa6a300]  "Microphone (Realtek Audio)"
[dshow @ 000001b24fa6a300]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{35EBFC89-7B09-4557-8032-85AA0B688FE9}"
```

But on popen I can't check it:

`-list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy: Invalid argument`

For the python part of the code I am using this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([getPathForFile("windows/ffmpeg").replace('\\','/'),  " -f gdigrab -offset_x 10 -offset_y 20 -show_region 1 -i desktop -video_size 1536x864 -b:v 2M -maxrate 1M -bufsize 1M -tune fastdecode -crf 15 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -qp 1 -y -an "+ path.replace('\\\\','/').replace('\\','/')+"video.mov"], shell=True)
```

The `getPathForFile` is a custom function that returns the path. this is correct, mainly because the errors I am getting are from the ffmpeg, so...

I am on a Windows 10. FFmpeg 4.0. Python 3.5.

Any ideas why am I getting these errors on Popen but not on command line and how to fix them? (mainly the second error)

Comment: Put each argument in its own string and turn of the shell. Like p = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg.exe", "-arg1", "blahblah", "-arg2", "blahblah2"]); p.communicate() . Ow, yeah, you don't have to turn backslashes to slashes.

Comment: <3 it worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Can you answer the question for me to accept it? If not, I can do it myself...

Comment: Certainly if you wish it. Just give me a sec.

Comment: Some additional notes: `-video_size 1536x864` is a [gdigrab input option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#gdigrab) so it should go before the `-i`. `-crf` and `-b:v` are mutually exclusive: use only one or the other. `-qp` is ignored by libx264. With input devices you should set the frame rate with the `-framerate` input option instead of the `-r` output option to avoid unnecessary frame rate conversion (default for gdigrab is 30000/1001). Trailing options may be ignored, so don't put any options past your output file name.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard *-qp is ignored by libx264* --> picked up here (`rc=cqp` as printed by x264).

Comment: @Gyan Yes, x264 does support `-qp`. That was a typo. Although I "read" and wrote `-qp`, but was thinking `-q:v` (a symptom of mild dyslexia–I think I've made this same typo here before) which I see users try to use much more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each argument in its own string and turn off the shell.
Like this:

```
import subprocess
import os

cmd = ["-f", "gdigrab", "-offset_x", "10", "-offset_y", "20",
    "-show_region", "1", "-video_size", "1536x864", "-i", "desktop",
    "-b:v", "2M", "-maxrate", "1M", "-bufsize", "1M", "-tune", "fastdecode",
    "-preset", "ultrafast", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
    "-r", "25", "-qp", "1", "-y", "-an",
    os.path.join(path, "video.mov")]

p = subprocess.Popen([getPathForFile("windows/ffmpeg")]+cmd)
p.communicate()
```